# Android slow canvas behavior when drawing bitmaps

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I'm developing a home brew family guy character creator for android. Basically you can choose a hair, beard, shirt, pants etc. for your character. I'm using the composite pattern to store the currently worn facial features and clothes. I'm using canvas to display the current state of the custom character the user is creating. When my activity starts the canvas draws 3 bitmaps instantly, but after that when the user clicks (touches) a hair type for example the drawing takes an unusual long amount of time to happen for some reason (sometimes even up to ~ 1 minute). I can't seem to find any reasonable explanation as to why this is happening. Thanks in advance.

A part of my onCreate overridden method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);

character = new Character();
character.attach(this); //observes the character

assetManager = getAssets();
BitmapLoader.setAssetManager(assetManager);

/*...*/

characterView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.character_view);

initCanvas();
initButtons();
loadPersistedCharacter();

character.notifyAllObservers(); //just for testing purposes
}
```

My canvas initialization code:

```
private void initCanvas() {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    Bitmap background = Bitmap.createBitmap(600, 800, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        canvas = new Canvas(background);

    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#CD5C5C"));
    characterView.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), background));
}
```

When a clothing or a facial feature is clicked (with the help of onClickListeners) through the use of the Observer pattern the update method gets invoked which can be found in the same Activity as the previous code.

```
@Override
public void update() {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    Skin skin = character.getSkin();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapLoader.load(skin.getPath());

canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);

float scale = skin.getScale();
int asd = bitmap.getWidth();
int asdY = bitmap.getHeight();

float coordX = (canvas.getWidth() - scale * asd) / skin.getXPosDivider();
float coordY = (canvas.getHeight() - scale * asdY) / skin.getYPosDivider();

RectF rect= new RectF(coordX, coordY, coordX + scale * bitmap.getWidth(), coordY + scale * bitmap.getHeight());

canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, null, rect, paint);

for (HeadFeature feature : character.getHeadFeatures()) {
    scale = feature.getScale();
    bitmap = BitmapLoader.load(feature.getPath());

    coordX = (canvas.getWidth() - scale * bitmap.getWidth()) / feature.getXPosDivider();
    coordY = (canvas.getHeight() - scale * bitmap.getHeight()) / feature.getYPosDivider();

    rect= new RectF(coordX, coordY, coordX + scale * bitmap.getWidth(), coordY + scale * bitmap.getHeight());

    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, null, rect, paint);
}
}
```

Comment: Are you drawing on a SurfaceView?  I don't see anything particularly taxing that would take up to a minute to draw. Also, if you're drawing on the main thread, you'd get an ANR crash (but drawing on a SurfaceView thread would not cause this).

Comment: Also small optimizations, you will get better performance if you don't create new objects like `Paint` or `RectF` each draw cycle.  Stash those away in the class level and update them using their setter methods.

Comment: thanks for the tips. I'm not using a SurfaceView but a simple LinearLayout. I tried using the SurfaceView but the onSurfaceCreated callback was never ever called. Plus with the SurfaceView I was not able to make the background transparent. I don't think that I am receiving an ANR crash, it is just not drawing it immediately for some odd reason. The drawing happens on the main thread I guess.

Comment: use RGB_565 instead ARGB_8888 as ARGB_8888 takes 4 byte for each pixel and encodes RGB + alpha channel whereas RGB_565 uses 2 byte per pixel and only encodes RGB little quality issue though. give it a try

Comment: I've tried that already. I even tried setting  android:hardwareAccelerated="true" and it helped but not by much.

Comment: If you're app isn't crashing then the issue isn't with the drawing. The app is supposed to crash after 5 seconds of not responding. I'd check where you're updating the state.

Comment: the app is responsive, but after my update method finished nothing changes on the canvas for at least another 30 seconds

Comment: Funny thing: if I insert a Toast.make(...).show(); before the part where I add the ie. hat to my character (after the correct button has been clicked) the change shows up nearly instantly, but if I remove the toast message I need to wait decades.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the following: my characterView LinearLayout was never invalidated and therefore it was rarely refreshed. The application simply did not know that my View should be refreshed. A simple call to characterView.invalidate() solved the problem.

```
public void update() {
    /*...*/
    characterView.invalidate();
}
```